# Position of centre of mass during toppling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Does the centre of mass shift in any way when it's about to topple, because a body toppling would simply mean that the weight vector is acting in a direction towards a point on the surface outside the body ?

I don't understand this situation in the case when the block is kept on a horizontal ground. Because when you exert a force on it, the normal force shifts in the direction of the force exerted. But the centre of mass is still in the same position of  the block. So, is it not necessary that the weight vector acting in a direction towards a point on the surface falls outside the body to enable it to topple? Or is there any change in position of the centre of mass ?

I guess I am really confused about this concept.

I will be really grateful to you if you make me understand this concept. Thank you.

Comment: You have several questions here, along with several misconceptions. Decide which question is most important.

Comment: can you tell me which questions have misconceptions ?@BillN

Comment: First 2 questions were deleted @BillN

Comment: Good. Those were the ones with misconceptions. Mainly, you can't apply a force to another force.  You can have two different forces acting on a common object and get a net force.

Comment: Weight acts on an object along a line through the center of mass of an object. Normal force is actually a distributed force acting on the object along the line of contact with whatever surface the object is touching. That distribution may be uniform or non-uniform. The normal force distribution can produce torque on the object.

Comment: @BillN So, is it not necessary for the weight of the body to act  through the edge of the part of the body which is in contact with the surface to enable toppling ? Because that is not changing if you are going on increasing the horizontal force on a block lying on a horizontal surface and yet its toppling when the normal force comes to the edge.

Comment: *normal force shifts in the direction of the force exerted* clarification needed as normal force acts perpendicular to the surface & not "in the direction of the force exerted."

Comment: Edit to my above comment:  Normal force is actually a distributed force acting on the object, *perpendicular to and distributed along* the line of contact with whatever surface the object is touching.

Comment: @KyleKanos I meant the "**shift**" is in the direction of the force, not that the normal force gets aligned in the direction of the force applied. I am not that bad...... hahaha

Comment: If the normal force acts at an edge of an extended object becuase a third force is tilting the object, you have to calculate the torque about the edge to see what direction the object rotates.

Comment: @BillN So, is it not necessary for the weight of the body to act through the edge of the part of the body which is in contact with the surface to enable toppling ? Because that is not changing (I guess u didn't read this question)

Comment: If the weight vector is *perfectly* acting through a sharp edge below it (gravity defines *downward*), the object will be in an unstable equilibrium. If the weight vector aligns to either side of the edge, the object will rotate that direction if no other forces are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because a body toppling would simply mean that the weight vector is acting in a direction towards a point on the surface outside the body ?

Well, the *weight* vector is always going to act straight down.  But other forces on the block  may cause it to fall.

What I didn't understand from your question was how the body began to topple.  Was it pushed, did it fail mechanically, did the ground give way, ...?

I'm going to assume it was pushed.  In the beginning, we just have a simple block sitting on the ground.

[image: Sitting block]

The weight vector points down and the supports of the block surround it, so there is no movement.  In particular, let's consider the (marked) bottom right corner.  Can the block pivot at this point and fall to the right?   No.  Even if we remove the ground under the block so that no normal force is present, the torque about the corner would make it fall to the left, not to the right.

Now we start pushing the block to the right with an additional force $F$.

[image: Pushed block]

Let's consider the torque exerted about the same corner on the right.  We have the original counter-clockwise torque from the weight of the block ($mgx$), but now a clockwise torque from the pushing ($Fy$).  If $Fy$ is greater than $mgx$, then the torque will be sufficient to accelerate the block around the corner and it will tip.

There is always a normal force holding up the block, but if it is tipping (or nearly tipping), then only the corner of the object can be supporting the weight.  Therefore the normal force moves until it is acting through the corner.

With no distance to act, there is no torque from the force, so we can ignore it for calculating if the tipping will happen.