# Tipping while moving forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, free-body-diagram

(This is a follow-up to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520805/calculating-the-angle-of-tipping-given-force-applied) question I asked earlier, but here let us consider a more general situation where the center of gravity is at a height $H$ above the base, and the force is applied at a height $h$.)

[image]

I understand that if the force applied is greater than $\dfrac{mgr}{h}$, i.e., if the force creates a greater torque than the weight force, the cylinder will tip.

If the force is lesser than that, but still greater than the maximum achievable friction $\mu mg$, it will slide.

My question is, what will happen if the force is greater than *both* $\dfrac{mgr}{h}$ *and* $\mu mg$?

Will it keep moving *while* tipping forward? Will it move some distance, and *then* topple down? Will it topple down first and *then* move forward?

How can we find the distance it would travel forward before toppling down entirely?

Comment: it slides until friction exceeds tipping force

Comment: How can friction exceed the tipping force? Is it not the tipping force that can exceed friction?
When the tipping force is greater than friction, there is a net horizontal resultant force, so mustn't it also accelerate forward while tipping?

Comment: it slides until friction exceeds tipping torque

Comment: You mean slides until friction equals to tipping torque, then it toppled over, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F\gt f$ then there is a resultant force $F-f$ acting on the cylinder so its COM has a linear acceleration $a=(F-f)/m$ to the right. There is also a resultant couple, which is initially $\tau=hf-mgr$, acting clockwise about B. Hence the cylinder also has an initial angular acceleration of $\alpha=\tau/I$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the cylinder about B (not about its centre of mass E).

So yes the cylinder topples while also accelerating to the right. How long it takes the cylinder to topple, and how far it moves before this happens, requires a very tricky calculation.

If $\alpha$ were constant then the time to topple onto its side through angle $\theta=\frac12 \pi$ radians would be $t=\alpha/\theta=2\alpha/\pi$. And the distance moved by the centre of mass E would be $s=\frac12 a t^2$.

**However** there are complications.

If $F$ is applied horizontally at a fixed point P then as the cylinder topples the vertical distance between P and B increases, while the horizontal distance between E and B decreases. So the torque $\tau$ and acceleration $\alpha$ do not remain constant; initially both increase as the angle which QE makes with the vertical increases. The increase in torque $\tau$ reduces the time $t$ which it takes for the cylinder to topple.

As the cylinder rotates its centre of mass E accelerates upwards. To enable this to happen the normal force $N$ acting at B must also increase. This in turn increases the friction force $f$ which in turn increases the torque on the cylinder, causing it to topple faster, and decreases the horizontal acceleration of E.

The simplified calculation above also assumes that point B remains in contact with the ground as the cylinder topples. But it is possible for the rotation of the cylinder to increase so much as it topples that at some stage point B leaves contact with the ground. Then $f$ becomes zero and the torque on the cylinder changes from clockwise to anticlockwise. It continues rotating, but now about E.

These factors affect each other, and if the cylinder leaves contact with the ground then its centre of rotation changes and it becomes a projectile until it regains contact with the ground. So it is a very tricky calculation.

Comment: "There is also a resultant couple, which is initially $τ=hf−mfr$, acting clockwise about B."
I don't quite get this. How can $f$ create a torque about $B$ when $f$ passes through $B$?
On a different note, can we use the principle of conservation of energy to find the distance it travels, the time it takes etc.?

Comment: The 2 forces $F$ and $f$ can be resolved into a resultant force $F-f$ which causes linear acceleration of the COM and a couple of equal and opposite forces $f$ separated by $h$, which causes rotational acceleration. Hence the value of $\tau$.

Comment: No you cannot use conservation of energy because the energy transfers are also very complicated to work out. $F$ is doing work which puts energy in, while sliding friction is taking energy out. There is also rotational energy as well as translational energy. All interacting in a complicated way.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I still do not see how there can be two equal forces $f$ separated by $h$. I can only understand that a force $F-f$ acts horizontally at a height $h$ above the base. I do not see how any other horizontal force can act. Can you please help me out?

Comment: The two forces $F$ and $f$ do not have the same line of action so there is also  a couple of size $fr$. Force $F$ can be replaced by a resultant force $F-f$ acting at P. This leaves $f$ acting forwards at P and $f$ acting backwards at B, forming the couple.

Comment: The original problem - what the forces must be for the cylinder to start to topple - was one of statics (forces in balance). There were no linear or rotational accelerations so the problem was simple. Your new problem is one of dynamics. The forces and couples are not balanced, there are linear and rotational accelerations, which make the problem harder.